# Selectively remove/disable syncing Google Drive documents on Chrome

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed the Google Docs app (extension) on Google Chrome (v43.0.2357.65 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on Ubuntu Linux 14.04), and enabled offline sync on my Google Drive account. Offline editing and sync for Docs works fine, but I cannot find a way to remove a synced document from my local Chrome app (for example, I would like to remove from the Docs app, documents that I have finished working with). Is there a way to remove such an already synced document from the local Docs app on Chrome?

Also, is there a way to prevent certain documents from being automatically synced in this way? (e.g. disabling sync for a selected doc on the Chrome app or the Google Drive interface)

**Note:** I'm not referring to the Drive desktop app, but to the Docs app available via Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

No, there isn't.

## Long Answer

The Google Docs app available via the Chrome Web Store actually works as a shortcut or bookmark to the web app.

The Google Docs offline capability, is actually a feature of the Google Drive web app. It requires Chrome to work, but not the Google Docs Chrome extension.

There isn't a way to select with files or folders will be synced.

**References**
[Access your files offline - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

Found an imperfect workaround.

Seems that Chrome stores its offline sync data under IndexedDB. Visiting a `docs.google.com` domain (e.g. an offline synced document) and clearing (truncating) a couple of tables under `Developer Console > Resources > IndexedDB > GoogleDocs` (using the `Clear object store` at the bottom) seemed to do the trick.

The following were the tables I cleared: `DocumentCommands`, `DocumentLocks`, `Documents`, `Comments`, `FileEntities`, `PendingQueues`, `Impressions`, and `DocumentEntities`. It may be possible to get things done by clearing a lesser number of tables, though.

**WARNING:** Truncation of tables clears **all** currently synced documents. However, it should be possible (programmatically or otherwise) to remove a selected set of documents by removing only the relevant entities from IndexedDB (using their document IDs, maybe).

By the way, this was on Google Chrome 48.0.2564.79 beta (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu).